# Lower bound of a function given its upper bound

Tags: calculus

I've just began studying Calculus 1 and I really need some help with this question. I have a function $f(x)$ which is defined for all $x \ge 0$. I also have a function $g(x)$ which is also defined for all $x \ge 0$ for which I know that $g(x) \ge f(x)$ for all $x$. The function $g(x)$ is strictly increasing and $f(x)$ is increasing (not strictly). Also, $g(x)=f(x)$ for some $x$ (for other $x$s, $g(x) > f(x)$). Can I then say there exists a constant $C$ such that 
$$
g(x) - C \le f(x)\;\text{ for all }\;x\ge 0?
$$ Thanks!

Comment: **Welcome to Mathematics Stack Exchange!** A quick [tour](https://math.stackexchange.com/tour) will enhance your experience. Here are helpful tips to [write a good question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question/9960#9960) and [write a good answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer).  For equations, please use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, you cannot conclude that. It's probably a good idea to get used to constructing counterexamples, and often something as simple as a polynomial will do the trick. In this case, let
$$
f(x) = x
$$
That's increasing, and defined for all positive $x$, so we're good. Now let
$$
g(x) = 2x
$$
That's also increasing and is always greater than or equal to $f(x)$, because $2x \ge x$ when $x > 0$.

But there's no such constant $C$. Why not? Well, suppose there was. Then for every value of $x \ge 0$, we'd have 
$$
2x - C < x
$$
and adding $C$ to both sides, and subtracting $x$ from both sides, that'd mean that for every $x$, we'd have
$$
x < C.
$$
But for $x = C + 1$, this claim is obviously false.

That's a little bit sloppy, because I'm assuming that $C > 0$ (as it usually is in problems like these). To clean it up: If $C$ is less than $-1$, this doesn't quite work, and we need to say that "for $x = \max(C+1, 0)$, it's obviously false."

Answer (score 1):

No. Let $g(x) = x, f(x) = 0$. Then $g(x) \ge f(x) $ for all $x \ge 0$, $g$ is strictly increasing, $f$ is non decreasing, but there is no $C$ such that $f(x) \ge g(x)-C$ for all $x$.